# Find out where back button press is going

Tags: android, back-button, onbackpressed

When user presses a back hardware button in my activity he will either be taken to a previous activity or to the home screen (depends on how he got into that activity in a first place). Is there a way to determine where exactly user will be taken inside of `onBackPressed` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your home and previous activity when you start the intent to go to this activity, you can add an extra to the Intent.

```
Intent.setExtra("PREVIOUS_ACTIVITY ", "HOME")
```

Then you can check in your activity onBackPressed() if it came from the home or another activity.